# Why are the operators so sloppy in hiding themselves?

Tags: realism, sicario-day-of-the-soldado

In the movie, *Sicario - Day of the Soldado*, the American operators set up a surveillance team above the high school campus where they would kidnap a cartel's boss's daughter.

[image]

but we can see form this screen shot, there are plenty of tall building around their position and any one curious enough to spy around with a binocular would have seen them, I am assuming it will take the Americans days to stay there before they are confident enough to act.

The only reason I can think of is their window is one-sided visible, e.g. you cannot see through from the outside.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: If someone did happen to see them, what would they see? Just a bunch of dudes chilling? There’s nothing obviously suspicious in your photo like weapons or a big whiteboard with “kidnap plan” written on it. Is the threat these guys pose known about such that people would be on the lookout for a bunch of tough looking guys hanging around near a school?

Comment: @Darren, good point. I should have taken account that we are more plot-aware as audience.

Comment: I don't know, if I saw a room full of mean looking men looking at school children through a telephoto lens... I'd definitely want to alert somebody.

Comment: Surveillance teams or secret agents in general are sloppy in real life, so why not in the movies.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing that may be considered sloppy would be the binocular lenses, otherwise it would be perfectly normal. You have to consider as well that they wante to pose as less professional on purpose so that they would be confused as a cartel hit related.

Comment: Correct. As Jeffrey Donovan's character says: "Sloppy is good. Sloppy makes it look like a cartel did it."